# A Borel measure function is also $\mu$ measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$: $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is l.s.c., where $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ is open bounded. Let $\mu$ be any Radon measure on $\Omega$.

Question: is $f$ $\mu$ measurable?

My try: I think the answer is yes. Since every l.s.c function is borel measurable, it is $\mu$ measurable as well since $\mu$ is a Radon measure.

Am I correct? If not, please hint me. Thank you!

Comment: Measurabililty is with respect to a $\sigma$-field, not a measure. In this case, $f$ is Borel measurable which is the $\sigma$-field underlying a Radon measure. So, in short, it is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-field underlying $\mu$.

Comment: "l.s.c." means "lower semi-continuous?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes

Comment: @copper.hat Thx!